# Creating a word document inside my Document library based on a list item will show the HTML for a Rich Text editor field

Tags: 2013, workflow, development, content-type, rich-text

I was exploring a way which allow me to export a list item as `.docx` file. And i keep trying and searching till i find this appraoch which sound promising to me [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/creating-word-documents-from-sharepoint-list-item-juan-de-roock).

This approach mainly include creating a word document, based on the list item fields using workflow. so i created the workflow, and i added the columns to the document template. and it worked well.

But when i did more deep testing i realize that if the list item have a column of type Rich Text (which is named "Project overview" in my case), and i will populate the column inside my workflow as follow:-

[image]

Then the rich text value inside the new document file will be displayed with all the HTML tags, as follow:-

[image]

and  if the Rich Text column have images inside it, then inside the word document the image will be shown as `<img>` instead of showing the actual image? so can anyone advice if i can show the Rich Text content including images inside my word document, using the above appraoch ?

Thanks

Comment: Word isn't based on HTML syntax and vice versa. If this is a must have, I'd consider some 3rd party tool used to handle the HTML-to-.docx conversion for your rich text field.

Comment: @moe Ok i got your point. now since i already spent time to implement this and testing it. so is replacing/removing all the content which appear inside `<>`  a valid option to try ? Second question. now my main requirement is that i want to export the list item as `.docx` file, regardless of following my above appraoch or not so is there a way to achieve this requirement inside sharepoint, using java-script or other methods ? i always got surprised how i can find technical articles over the web as the one I followed and it is being rated by users, but at the same time it have major bugs in it!

Comment: 1: You want to focus on the content between `<div` and `div>`  tags, as there are several `<`s and `>`s in your example. 2: I believe you have already found a blog post doing the .docx exporting. It's hard to provide a 100% universally working solution. I understand your need is to have a completely content extracting and to .docx importing solution, but expecting e.g. `<img>`-contents to be formatted as Word's images is almost absurd. There are limitations which can't be surpassed without an external help - which in this case would be a 3rd party tool to handle the conversion.

Comment: There are also other similar solutions for your requirement, but I'm pretty sure by following them you'd face the same issue with rich text fields. [Solution 1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129676/export-item-in-view-form-to-a-word-document) & [Solution 2](https://sharepointprojectbrad.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/create-word-2013-documents-from-sharepoint-2013-list-items/).

Comment: @moe now the solution1 & solution2 are almost the same as the appraoch i am currently following.. which have problems when dealing with rich text columns... now i think the way i should be doing things ,, is to follow this appraoch but i need to do these 2 modifications; 1) remove all the html tags,, and i have to live with the face that the images need to be removed also.. and users should manually add them to the .docs file... but i am not sure if sharepoint 2010 provide a function which will allow me to remove the html tags from the rich text column content ???

Comment: As I must repeat now, yes, the solutions 1 and 2 are similar and likely end up with the same issue. **No**, there's no built-in function to do the pre-formatting in SharePoint. Calculated columns in theory could've been (only partly) helpful, but you can't use them with Rich Text fields.